# Splitting MailMerge doc: why is the last doc empty?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Title says it all - mostly. This is my first Word macro.
I try to split the result of a MailMerge into separate files. Logic seems good to me, but the very last doc is always empty. Any idea why ?

I noticed that there is no section mark at the end the the Merged doc.
The macro is called when the MailMerge doc is activated.

```
Sub SplitDoc()
    Dim sec As Section, doc As Document, fn As String
    Dim targetfolder As String

    targetfolder = "Y:\\"   'ignore this :-)

     For Each sec In ActiveDocument.Sections
        sec.Range.Copy
        Set doc = Documents.Add
        doc.Range.Paste
        fn = Mid(Split(doc.Paragraphs(3).Range.Text, ", ")(0), 5)
        Debug.Print Now, fn

       'Removes the break that is copied at the end of the section, if any.
        With doc.Sections.Last.Range
            .MoveStart wdCharacter, -1
                       '============= here is the issue: 
                       'for the last section (without ending section mark)
            .Delete    'it deletes the empties the whole doc
        End With
        'restore page setup that was stored in the section break
        With doc.PageSetup
            .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2)
            .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2)
            .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2)
            .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2)
        End With

        doc.SaveAs FileName:=fn & ".docx"
        doc.Close
        Set doc = Nothing
     Next sec
     Debug.Print Now, "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: A letter merge outputs a Section break after every record; hence the final, empty, Section. Instead of re-inventing the wheel, you might care to look at the topics *Send Mailmerge Output to Individual Files* and *Split Merged Output to Separate Documents* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** thread at http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html or http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/163017-Word-Mailmerge-Tips-amp-Tricks

Comment: @macropod great page indeed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to remove the section break at end of output doc was emptying the document when no section break was present.

```
        With doc.Sections.Last.Range
            .MoveStart wdCharacter, -1
            .Delete
        End With
```

replaced by

```
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "^b"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
```